# Centering Screen to Content of the Layer in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there a way to center your view screen to content of the layer. So when you have lots of layers and you want to know what does this layer belong too and is not named to give a hint. Then can't you just hold some key click it and it will take you to the content.

It'd be very useful. If there is a script to do it..I'd appreciate that too.

Comment: This is really a tech support, "How do I use the program" question. It's not about design.

Comment: It's a "user awareness of functionality" question. How is that inappropriate and not about design?

Comment: It is a tech support question and a great example of why you should learn how to name your layers and structure your document effectively.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the unrelatedness of my question from design and everything that goes with it. And also for reminding me what a wonderful community of moderators we have in All SE and SO sites that i almost had forgotten. I am sure to spread the word around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selection Aware Zoom is not something Adobe places ANY interest in creating. Despite this feature existing in many other professional design applications, Adobe doesn't care for it.

The best alternative to solving your "user awareness of current layer bounds" is to turn on this: [Highlighted in GREEN]

It's not perfect, not even close. The ideal would be a Shift+Z for "zoom to bounds of selected", or something similar. Good luck getting Adobe to ever realise the usefulness of something like this.

[image: View Layer Edges ON!]